# Прога на питоне

Tags: python

нужно написать программу с помощью которой питон узнает максимальное количество попыток введения пин кода которые придётся ввести человеку что бы разблокировать смартфон, и какое кол-во секунд на это понадобиться ?

**формат исходных данных**

программе выдаётся на вход четыре пари цифр (li;ri) (0≤li≤ri≤9;1≤i≤4). каждая такая пара записана в отдельном рядку и означает диапазон в котором за предположением  находиться определённая цифра пин кода

**Выходные сведения**

в первом рядку введите максимальное количество попыток ввести пин код которую нужно будет сделать  что бы разблокировать телефон . в втором максимальное количество секунд необходимую  что бы его разблокровать

```py
def is_valid(pin_code):
    return pin_code.isnumeric() and len(pin_code) in (4, 6)
def is_valid(pin_code):
    return len(pin_code) in (4,6) and pin_code.isdigit()
from re import match
def is_valid(pin_code):
    return bool(match("\d{4}$|\d{6}$", pin_code))
```

этот код не подходит

помогите пожайлуста дурочку

Comment: а если без кода - как вообще вы предлагаете решить данную задачу? т.е. что именно надо сделать?

Comment: нужно написать программу с помощью которой питон узнает максимальное количество попыток введения пин кода которые придётся ввести человеку что бы разблокировать смартфон